# Can I create ad-hoc connection over VPN?

Tags: vpn, adhoc-network

I need to connect two machines, one of which is a tiny Linux computer capable *only* of ad-hoc Wi-Fi connections. The problem is, the two machines are at two remote geographic locations, so direct ad-hoc Wi-Fi is not an option. The connection has to go over the internet.

The question is: can I put a VPN-capable router next to the ad-hoc-only machine, then another router with the other computer, and then create a VPN tunnel over the internet? My hope is that the VPN would function like a repeater and let the two machines connect via a "virtual" ad-hoc connection.

Comment: not to sure what your meaning by ad-hoc? at a guess you may need a bridge the networks together at layer 2 , using a layer 3 vpn.  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html

Comment: By ad-hoc I mean whatever is meant when you normally connect two laptops using ad-hoc WiFi.

Also, by VPN I mean the usual VPN capability that any off-the-shelf router has, it won't be anything fancy. (Very likely it will be a Novatel MiFi 2352, because it's so tiny and has a battery - just like the Linux machine.)

Comment: If it can *honestly* only connect in Ad-Hoc mode, it's unlikely you are going to find a router that works in Ad-Hoc mode, most use Infrastructure mode.  For the MiFi, the review here http://www.filesaveas.com/novatelmifi2352.html claims it's "ad-hoc" but in the screenshot listing networks, it's clearly in Infrastructure mode (note the icon for "print server", this is an ad-hoc mode connection).  You will need to have a second computer with both a wireless card (to connect Ad Hoc to this Linux machine) and a separate internet connection.